# Why is command.data undefined when all of my commands are exporting data objects in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So currently I have a bot that uses discord.js and every time I try to use my `deploy-commands.js` file, I get an undefined error that says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` (when reading `command.data.name`). This has confused me because apparently, from reading other articles similar to this one, it's usually due to someone having a file that does not export a data object in their commands folder; however, all of mine do. What can I do to fix this?

my `deploy-commands.js` file:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, token } = require('./config.json');

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const buttonCommands = [];
const buttonCommandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'buttonCommands');
const buttonCommandFiles = fs.readdirSync(buttonCommandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of buttonCommandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(buttonCommandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    buttonCommands.push(command);
}

module.exports = { buttonCommands };


(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

image of all of my commands for reference:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqtn0.png)

if it's needed, here is also a link to a sourcebin that shows the code for all of these commands and my index.js file: https://srcb.in/mtqWFVLAeN

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = { buttonCommands };
```

It looks like here you are only exporting `buttonCommands`, but not `commands`.

Comment: Tried this, gave same error. I tried logging each of the file names before it errored in the for loop, and it seems like an issue with my characters.js file (which happens to have a data object with a name being exported). Still not really sure what the issue is

Comment: Update, figured out it was a circular dependency issue between my index.js and my commands that required index.js. Still not sure what exactly to do, but I'm trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now-- the core of the problem was I just needed to make my commands not require index.js. I made a new js file and put all my variables in a class in there and just exported/required the class instead.